# How to specify a name for index (@Column(unique = true)) SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, sql-server-2008-r2, indexing

Unique constraint is implemented by unique index in Sql Server 2005/2008 for the following:

```
@Column(name = "SOME_ID", unique = true)
public String getSomeId() {
    return someId;
}
```

Sql Server generates `UQ__USERS__135061FE4316F928`, is it possible to specify a user defined name from hibernate?

There is no `name = XYZ` for `@Column`. 
`@org.hibernate.annotations.Index` does have a `name` however, I couldn't find a way to specify a unique index in that case.

I'm using JPA/Hibernate 4.1.9, SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a known issue and as discussed in the comments of this jira. [HB-1245](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HB-1245) the work around would be to export the schema and tweak the DDL to add the constraint names.